# Silex SecurityServiceProvider, anonymous setting doesn't work

Tags: php, silex

Right now I'm developing a simple API for a continuous integration server with Silex.
Now the api should be accessible to everyone with secret key, but for logged in users I want api to be available without any key.

Now the configuration for SecurityServiceProvider looks like this:

```
'security.firewalls' => array(

    'login' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/auth/login'
    ),
    'secured' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/',
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => "/auth/login",
            'check_path' => "/auth/dologin",
            'username_parameter' => 'login[username]',
            'password_parameter' => 'login[password]',
            "csrf_parameter" => "login[_token]",
            "failure_path" => "/auth/login",
        ),
        'logout' => array(
            'logout_path' => "/auth/logout",
            "target" => '/',
            "invalidate_session" => false
        ),
        'users' => array(
            // admin:foo
            'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg==')
        )
    ),'api' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/api',
        'anonymous' => true
    ),
)
```

The sad thing is that when I'm on /api/ pages it still redirects me to login page, although as you can see anonymous => true.

I can move firewall for /api at the top and remove anonymous line, but then I don't have access to SecurityContext object to check if user is authenticated.

Answer (score 3):

Allow anonymous users in general and use access rules to define protected areas:

```
// init the firewall
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
'security.firewalls' => array(
    'general' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/',
        'anonymous' => true,
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/login',
            'check_path' => '/admin/login_check'
        ),
        'users' => $app->share(function  () use( $app)
        {
            return new UserProvider($app);
        }),
        'logout' => array(
            'logout_path' => '/admin/logout',
            'target_url' => '/goodbye'
        )
    )
),
'security.access_rules' => array(
    array('^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
),
'security.role_hierarchy' => array(
    'ROLE_ADMIN' => array('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH')
)
```

));

If you want protect all except /api just define two firewalls:

```
// init the firewall
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
'security.firewalls' => array(
    'anonymous' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/api',
        'anonymous' => true
    ),
    'general' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/',
        'anonymous' => false,
        ...
    )
),
```

Comment: I want to protect everything, except /api/.

Comment: In this case define two firewalls (see example above).

Comment: It still redirects to login page. I said this in initial question. I can access /api without logging in without this line "'anonymous' => true", but after adding it, Silex redirects to /login.

Comment: ok - this seems to be the wrong way. So, what's about to create a 'API_USER' user for all which are not authenticated and log them in automatically? You can assign them the role API_USER and handle the KEY by checking the role?